# Laravel Stripe Mocking

Tags: laravel, mocking, stripe-payments

How can we mock Stripe in Laravel Unit Tests without using any external package like stripe-mock etc?

The job is to test the Controller feature where the secret is hardcoded and due to which test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i ran into the same problem,
i am using aspectmock from codeception. Gave me some grief setting it up but im now able to mock all the responses with a json response. this way the json data goes thru the stripe classes and it throws the correct errors and returns the same objects.
hope that helps
https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

```
public function testAll()
{
    $customerClass = new StripeCustomers();
    test::double('Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient', ['request' => [json_encode($this->allJsonData), 200, []]]);
    $customer = $customerClass->all();
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('data', $customer);
}
```